# Filter over [Maybe a] and discard Nothing values

Tags: list, haskell, filter, map-function, option-type

With a list of `Maybe a`, how to filter and take only the elements of the list which are not `Nothing`?

```hs
-- input
pas = [Just 3, Just 1, Just 5, Just 9, Nothing, Just 10, Nothing] :: [Maybe Int]

-- expected output
new_pas = [3, 1, 5, 9, 10]
```

I've tried different ways of using `map` and looked at `mapMaybe` but can't find the right combination.

Comment: `map` by itself can't filter. `concat . map (\case Nothing -> [] ; Just x -> [x])` would. (of course, your list comprehension answer shows it nicer written with LCs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As well as the simple list comprehension you found, there is already a library function for this: [catMaybes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes)

And note that you can search Hoogle not only for names, but for type signatures - something which is really useful in many situations. Here entering `[Maybe a] -> [a]` gives you `catMaybes` straight away. (Confession: I'd forgotten the name of the function, but knowing it existed, found it exactly that way just now!)

Answer (score 4):

While typing the question I've found the answer and it's actually straightforward:

```hs
new_pas = [pa | Just pa <- pas]
-- [3, 1, 5, 9, 10]
```

Putting it here for other people Googling the same question.

Answer (score 0):

[Your way with pattern-matching in list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64441466/11143763) is quite nice. Yet, I also like the way [`Data.Maybe.mapMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Data.Maybe.html#mapMaybe) you mentioned (note that it is just one line under [`Data.Maybe.catMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes) spoken of in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64442043/11143763) by [Robin Zigmond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8475054/robin-zigmond)) could be used here:

```hs
unwrapJusts :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
unwrapJusts = mapMaybe id
```

Your example:

```
GHCi> unwrapJusts [Just 3, Just 1, Just 5, Just 9, Nothing, Just 10, Nothing]
[3,1,5,9,10]
```

The idea is fairly simple: when traversing through the list `mapMaybe id` throws all the `Nothing`s (which are `id Nothing`s) away and turns `Just x`s into `x`s.